# How should a common part of a page be treated within the page object pattern?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm in the middle of creating page objects in java for automated UI testing. I'm trying to follow the page object pattern and I'm wondering how a common part of the website falls into the paradigm? For instance the AUT has many different pages for running reports, the left pane for selecting a report, date ranges, filtering, etc is common for all pages. So should I create a different page object for this common area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...The main aim of PageObjects are to represent repetitive parts of application, so through out your tests suite information of such repetitive part remains in single PageObject.

> ***PageObject need not represent an entire page. It may represent a section that appears many times within a site or page, such as site
>   navigation.***
>
> ***The essential principle is that there is only one place in your test suite with knowledge of the structure of the HTML of a particular
>   (part of a) page.***

***Reference*** -
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects